# Set variable value based on screen size

Tags: css, sass

I'm using sass. I want to add button paddings depending on the screen size. My only requirement is to have button `padding: 8px 8px;` for small screens and button `padding: 5px  8px;` for large screens. This is how I planned to have my sass variables.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    $paddingvar: 8px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    $paddingvar: 5px;
}
```

The problem I'm having is, `$paddingvar` is undefined.

NOTE: I'm calling this variable file as the first on the scss file

```
@import 'vars/_mediabased.scss'; /*$paddingvar is set here*/
@import 'other/_other.scss'; /*$paddingvar is used here*/
```

How can I set get the padding variable to work?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible. SASS is a compiled language so, any variables, mixins, etc. are compiled into CSS before run time. Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not set a variable inside a media query.
You could define the variables before the media queries and use as shown below:

```
/**
 * vars/_mediabased.scss
 */
$padding: 5px  8px;
$paddingtouch: 8px;


/**
 * other/_other.scss
 */
button {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    padding: $padding;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
    padding: $paddingtouch;
  }
}
```